# Why this code gives runtime error?

Tags: arrays, function, pointers, arguments

Passing a 2-d array to a function.
Why run time error in this code ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void cpc(int **x){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<3;printf("\n"),i++)
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    printf("%d ",(*(*(x+i)+j)));
    }
}
int main(){
int a[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int **b = (int**)a ;
cpc(b);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is **printf("\n")** and where is the opening parenthesis for first loop

Comment: @Abhi that don't create any issues..surely

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is a[3][3] is not a int **, it is an int * and it is contiguous memory.

This is one of the ways your code can work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void cpc(int **x){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<3;printf("\n"),i++)
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    printf("%d ",(*(*x+(3*i)+j)));
    }
}
int main(){
int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int *b = a;
cpc(&b);
return 0;
}
```

If you want to have a int ** like you are using in your cpc function you should allocate your row memory dinamically in your matrix.  Here you can find an example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void cpc(int **x){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<3;printf("\n"),i++)
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    printf("%d ",(*(*(x+i)+j)));
    }
}
int main(){
int *a[3];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
  for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
    a[i][j] = i*3+j;
}
int **b = a;
cpc(b);
return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.